# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [143, 426]

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

How can I fix this error it throws? ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:[143, 426]

```
#split the data set into independent (X) and dependent (Y) data sets
X = df.iloc[:,2:31].values
Y = df.iloc[:,1].values

#split the data qet into 75% training and 25% testing
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

#scale the data (feature scaling)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

#Using Logistic Regression Algorithm to the Training Set

classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

and the shape of X_train, Y_train:

```
X_train.shape
(143, 29)
Y_train.shape
(426,)
```

error msg:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2
3 classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
----> 4 classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
5 #Using KNeighborsClassifier Method of neighbors class to use Nearest Neighbor algorithm
6

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
210     if len(uniques) > 1:
211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
213
214

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [143, 426]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug at line 11 where you are assigning to X_train instead of X_test. Take a look at the corrected code below.

```
#split the data set into independent (X) and dependent (Y) data sets
X = df.iloc[:,2:31].values
Y = df.iloc[:,1].values

#split the data qet into 75% training and 25% testing
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

#scale the data (feature scaling)
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#Using Logistic Regression Algorithm to the Training Set

classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Also do not use fit_transform on X_test. You want use the same mean and std as that calculated in X_train.

Comment: thanks for the correction the problem in X_train, Y_train not equal in rows [143, 426] i think im new at this and i dk how to correct it

Comment: If this answers your question, please check the tick mark on the left side of the answer :)

Comment: @AcilFarhat the number of samples in X_train and Y_train must be equal. That is, X_train.shape[0] == Y_train.shape[0]. Make sure you have exactly the same number of data points in X_train and Y_train.